# How to make sure that the images do not move when the page is compressed?

Tags: html, css

I want that when folding the page, my blocks (images) do not move to the side. How to do it?

It should be like that :

[image]

But works like that :

[image]

When I collapse the page, the div dws doesn't move anywhere (I mean the picture). And the swd div moves down.

```css
.dws-wrapper {
  width: 480px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 210px auto 0;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  background: linear-gradient(20deg, #f00, #00f);
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 50%;
  right: 14.3%;
}

.swd-wrapper {
  width: 480px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 210px auto 0;
  position: relative;
  background: linear-gradient(20deg, #f00, #00f);
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  overflow: hidden;
  left: 16%;
  margin-top: -25.1%;
}
```

```html
<div class="dws-wrapper">
  <a href="Panic!AtTheDisco.html">
    <img src="PanicAtTheDisco1.jpg" alt="PanicAtTheDisco" />
    <div class="dws-text">
      <h2>Panic!</h2>
      <h2>At the</h2>
      <h2>Disco</h2>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="swd-wrapper">
  <a href="TheNeighbourhood.html">
    <img src="I Love You_.jpg" alt="TheNeighbourhood" />
    <div class="swd-text">
      <h2>The</h2>
      <h2>Neighbourhood</h2>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Make width dynamic. If your browser window is 500px width, then obvious 2x480px divs will not fit in one line

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean that "move"?
Is it either don't small picture's size or don't move picture's position?

Comment: i mean dont move pictures

Comment: Please do not post an answer to comment. you need 50 [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) to post a comment. Until then, focus on the questions you can answer without more details.